# Unpublish file in Ubuntu one

Tags: ubuntu-one

I published some files in ubuntuone - now I wanted to unpublish these files. The files however, are marked as unpublished on my computer and on the u1 web interface. So, I cant unpublish them as they appear as unpublished. The links, however, are still active and accessible and in the ubuntu one app on my pc I can see these files listed in the "Share links" tab.

I also tried to unpublish with

```
u1sdtool --unpublish-file=PATH
```

to no avail.

Further, even if I delete the file from my pc, the link is still active and the file can be still downloaded from the public link!

Any idea how to resolve that issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found the (silly) source of my inability to unpublish a file. 
Whenever I send a large file as attachment with Thunderbird I'm asked to link that file via U1. If I agree, Thunderbird will copy that file into the "Thunderbird Attachments" folder on U1. That is, I'm not actually publishing the file that I was referring to in the mail attachment but the copy of that file which resides in the Thunderbird folder. 
Hence, trying to "unpublish" the original file will obviously not work.